# How do I use Fastxml algorithm in python to predict the value of the output column?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning

So far I managed to structure the dataset like this:
[image: init dataset]

I want to predict the diagnosis field based on the all other fields with python and fastxml.
I assigned integers to all diagnosis terms.

Ex.
When I find 'hypertensive' this word I replaced that with 1, when I find 'diabetes' i replaced with 2 and so on...

then the diagnosis column becomes like:
[image: after categorizing]

but when I'm trying to predict the diagnosis it gives the same result for all prediction.
Here is my snippet code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

from fastxml import Trainer, Inferencer
from fastxml.weights import propensity
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

trainer = Trainer(n_trees=8, n_jobs=1, leaf_classifiers=True)
trainer.fit([csr_matrix(X_train)], lt)
#trainer.save('fastxml_model.h5')
clf = Inferencer('fastxml_model.h5')
predict_mat=np.array([[14,1,78,70,140,80,178,80]])
scaler = StandardScaler().fit_transform(predict_mat)

res=clf.predict(csr_matrix(scaler.astype(np.float32)))
print(res)
```

Ouput is comming:

```
  (0, 14207)    -5.445482
  (0, 15876)    -0.13862942
  (0, 21138)    -0.13862942
  (0, 33919)    -0.13862942
  (0, 43647)    -0.13862942
  (0, 46255)    -0.13862942
```

Which is same for all..

Expected output:

```
hypertension,diabetes mellitus type 2,chronic kidney disease,parkinsonism
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: This question should be reopened. 1. I added the desired output 2. The specific only one problem is, this algorithm is giving same output for all prediction. 3. I want correct prediction 4. The pictures that I've added, removal of single picture makes this question vague. 5. I have posted what algorithm I used. The code can't be shorter than that. 6. People are busy. If i don't mention the imports in code, they just don't have time to figure out those imports and try that by themselves. 7. Look at those upvotes. If people felt this is a vague question, they would pressed the down vote.

Comment: PabitraRoy: seems you want to do multiclass classification for 200+ classes, in your case you really need to train 200+ individual classifiers, one for each diagnosis. Please rewrite your code to do that, edit it into the question, then as long as that has an MCVE and a clear statement of your problem, it'll be ok to be reopened - if it's a coding question. (If it's a statistical question, it belongs on CrossValidated.)

Comment: (But please also read the existing questions/blogs/tutorials on Multiple Classifiers System for Medical Diagnosis. Or ensembles.)

Comment: Also: start small. Pick say your three most common diagnosis codes: 91, 115, and whatever the third one is. Train a classifier for each of them. Get that working first before you go bigger. Good luck.